# SlamData uninstall Linux

Tags: centos7, slamdata

Does anyone know how to uninstall SlamData on a Linux system (Centos 7)? I would like to completely remove it from the server. I looked through the documentation but could not find anything on uninstallation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can uninstall SlamData simply by removing the directory you specified during the initial installation.  By default it ends up being

> /home/username/SlamData version

There is also a configuration directory and file you can delete located at

> /home/username/.config/quasar/quasar-config.json